# Using read.csv in R - Opening a dataset where the file name contains a word/phrase

Tags: r, csv

```
#set working directory
setwd("C:/Bucky/Locations/London")

#open survey data
survey.data <- read.csv("01-London-Dataset.csv")
```

I am looking to analyse multiple datasets which contain the same information for different locations. Each dataset is saved in a folder alongside other files relating to that location.

The file names are all structured in the same format - (01-London-Dataset.csv) - and no other file name in the folder will contain the word Dataset.

Is it possible to use read.csv to open the file that contains the word Dataset once the correct working directory is set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that in one line

```
read.csv(list.files(pattern = "Dataset"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I wanted it to and I've accepted your answer.